# Execute Python Script On ec2 Through ssh Throws Import Errors When Script Works

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, ssh, pip

I currently have a python script that is held on ec2. I can ssh into the ec2, navigate to the script, and run the python script as I have pip installed all the necessary packages. When I try to do so remotely like so:

ssh -i "key.pem" ec2-user@<ec2_address> "python <path_to_script>/test.py"

It throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<path_to_script>/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import geopandas as gpd
ImportError: No module named geopandas
```

Why is it that when I'm ssh connected to the instance and run the script it works with all my pip installed modules, but when I try the same command remotely, it cannot register the pip installed modules?

Comment: Where are the modules installed on the remote system? Do you have to set environment variables on the remote system for the script to work? How are these environment variables set?

Comment: I didn't have to set any environment variables. What I did was install python 3.8 and pip on my amazon linux ec2. Then I just pip installed all my necessary modules when I was ssh'd into the ec2. It looks like that the packages are stored here: /home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages

Comment: You say you also installed python 3.8? Where is this installed? Does the system have another copy of python installed somewhere?

Comment: I believe so. Since I used the Amazon Linux ec2 image there was already python 2.7 installed. I installed 3.8 and created an alias python="python3"

Comment: Okay, so you have to set an _alias_ for the script to work? Where is this _alias_ set?

Comment: I set the alias by ssh into the ec2 and modifying .bash_profile and then executing source ~/.bash_profile